# Why is it possible to run Linux containers on docker in MacOS

Tags: linux, macos, docker, operating-system, containers

Please correct me if there are any issues in my understanding of Docker and operating systems.

From what I understand, Docker uses the underlying kernel of the OS of the machine running the Docker engine. As a result you are not able to run Windows containers on a Linux machine as it requires Windows kernel. My question is how am I able to run CentOS, Ubuntu containers on my MacOS machine, given that MacOS does not use a Linux kernel even though they are both Unix based.

Comment: Docker Desktop for Mac _does_ run a Linux kernel, but the virtual machine it uses is hard to access directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It runs on a VM. More info [here](https://collabnix.com/how-docker-for-mac-works-under-the-hood/)